# React-Native assign a JSON Object fetched from url to a variable

Tags: javascript, json, variables, react-native, fetch

I'm having troubles with JSON data fetching on react-native, [here](http://discaricaabusivadibyte.altervista.org/IngBioSched/PROFS.json)'s the Json data I need, I wrote this code:

```
function getJsonData(){
  return fetch('http://discaricaabusivadibyte.altervista.org/IngBioSched/PROFS.json')
.then((res)=> res.json())
.then((responseJson) => { return responseJson.lista})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
}
var resp=getJsonData();
console.log("faischifo");
console.log(resp.primoanno[0]);
```

Logs: "5173 10207 E ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'resp.primoanno[0]')"

If I wrap responseJson.lista into a console.log function I see my JSON string formatted. But I can't assign it to a variable. Could you help me please?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jaws pointed out, your function `getJsonData` returns a promise, not the actual value of `responseJson.lista`.

Here's a runnable snippet, you might notice that I changed the `url` that is because your original link wasn't `https` and fetch fails with the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   '...'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   '...'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```js
function getJsonData() {
  return fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mamodom/90a441ac8dababa7b68015a9b506fee5/raw/69e247f03b5732b359b7e258ecae47f8e078131a/foo.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(responseJson => responseJson.lista)
    .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
}

getJsonData().then(data => {
  console.log("faischifo");
  console.log(data.primoanno[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have a problem.. When I fetch to get the whole API, it doesn't allow me to access it as a JSON Object. if I put the whole data into a variable previously created named "data" and then I type console.log(data.primoanno[0])  after the fetch chain the logs say "undefined is not an object".. even if I stringify it and re-parse it I get the same error.... the only way to access to some data is by mapping it.. but I just need the whole object as Json.. Is there any way to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Here, getJsonData returns a promise, so you'll need to access it as such.

```
getJsonData().then((data) => { console.log(data.primoanno[0] }
```